# How to add Laravel 4 to shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hosting, shared-hosting

I'm trying to add my laravel 4 application to my shared hosting.
The problem I'm having is that I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/webkrunc/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/webkrunc/public_html/index.php on line 21

Maybe someone can see where I made my mistake.

My folder structure:

```
webkrunch.co.za/ (domain root)
    -- main-laravel
    -- public_html
        -- with laravel files
```

in my main-laravel/bootstrap/paths.php I have:

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel/app',
'public' => __DIR__,
'base' => __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel/app/storage',
```

and in my public_html/index.php I have:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have set too many segments away in here

```
require __DIR__.'/../../main-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

try playing with removing one by one and see the effects. It must work, I have come across similar things before

Comment: sorry I mistook the question with another one. How have you been changing the segments? have you tried instead then to add another one?

Comment: I've realised something and I'm not sure how to fix it. My error is showing that it's line 21 but it should be line 22

Comment: I figured it out and I feel so stupid. I've been uploading the wrong file. I'm so sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your `public` folder contents to `public_html` folder. Then follow below steps.

Make paths.php like

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../main-laravel/app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
'base' => __DIR__.'/../main-laravel',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../main-laravel/app/storage',
```

Make index.php look like

```
require __DIR__.'/../main-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../main-laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```